# JavaFX FXMLoader IllegalStateException: Location is not set

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, fxmlloader

I try to load an FXML file `MainView.fxml` like it did it in some other projects. But I get `"IllegalStateException: Location is not set."` But I am pretty sure that I pass in the right location. Do you have any other ideas what could be wrong? I have no ideas anymore.

MainView.fxml is in Package View. App.java and View are on same Level.

Code:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/View/MainView.fxml"));

Parent root = loader.load();
Scene scene = new Scene(root);
```

Pathtree:

[image: pathtree]

Output:

```
    /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Didea.launcher.port=7532 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ant-javafx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/dt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/javafx-mx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jconsole.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/packager.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/sa-jdi.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/Volumes/Data/Users/oliver/Documents/workspace/LightningConsole/JavaFXClient/target/classes:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain App
Exception in Application start method
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$152(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$2/883049899.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2438)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2413)
    at App.start(App.java:16)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$159(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$53/955377530.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$172(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$49/1753120547.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$170(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$51/749139185.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$171(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$50/1077220155.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Try to debug if getClass().getResource("/View/MainView.fxml") is returning null or a Url. I guess its null so you have to find out how to proper load your resource

Comment: Try `getResource("View/MainView.fxml")` instead of `getResource("/View/MainView.fxml")` (without first slash)

Comment: I just solved it. When I putted my fxml file to resources folder I got my resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just solved it. When I putted my fxml file to resources folder I got my resource.

Now I have to find out why java search in resource folder and not in src! Anyone else?

Comment: [API-Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource-java.lang.String-) for `Class.getResource()` will be your best friend. It's all about the first slash in front of your Path-String. Ressource folder is a java default folder, so it's always in the classpath.

Comment: The Maven Compiler Plugin compiles all Java files in src/main/java by default and writes the class files to ${project.build.outputDirectory} (target/classes by default). The Maven Resources Plugin copies files from src/main/resources to ${project.build.outputDirectory}. So class files and resource files will end up in ${project.build.outputDirectory}. The Maven Resources Plugin ignores files in src/main/java by default. The Maven Jar Plugin will then zip ${project.build.outputDirectory} to a JAR file.

Answer (score 3):

Try this without all:

```
XMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
loader.setLocation(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("RootLayout.fxml"));
```